# Unable to pass data to view from controller in zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm doing a maintenance project with Zend Framework 1. I'm facing an issue that I'm not able to pass data from the controller to view (script). I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below is my code.

```
public function getHtmlAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('get-html');
    try {
        if ((!$page_data = self::getMenu())) {
            throw new Exception('Some error occoured while getting page data');
        }


        $this->view->assign('data', $page_data);
        return $this->view->render('get-html.phtml');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And inside view script i.e ***get-html.phtml***. If I'm using echo statement like below then I'm getting a blank array as `Array()`.

`<?php
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->getVars()); die();
?>`

Please suggest me what's wrong with this code.

Comment: You need to close the `<pre>` tag (add `</pre>` after printing the vars and before `die()`...

Comment: The code works still the same. By the way, the **_<pre>_** tag is auto closed when comes into execution. But still, I tried your solution. The output is still the same i.e. blank array.

Comment: If you dump out `$page_data` in your controller does it contain data?

Comment: Yes, it contains data as an exception will be thrown in case of no data.